# The withdraw/deposit function wont run

Tags: java

The program is meant to run a 5 second timer where at the end of each 5 seconds the program either deposits or withdraws an amount of money but for some reason this wont run! we also have to add a start and stop simulation button. how would i do this? Thanks for your help

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package bank;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author B00640241
 */
public class MainMenu2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextArea textOpen;
    double BalanceCheck;
    private Object intialDeposit;

    private final
    /**
     * Creates new form MainMenu2
     */
    public MainMenu2() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated
    // Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        currentAccount = new javax.swing.JButton();
        savingAccount = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        transactionHistoryA = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Main Menu");

        currentAccount.setText("Current Account ");
        currentAccount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                currentAccountActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        savingAccount.setText("Savings Account ");
        savingAccount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                savingAccountActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Transaction History ");

        jLabel2.setText("Errors");

        transactionHistoryA.setColumns(20);
        transactionHistoryA.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(transactionHistoryA);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(currentAccount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 140,
                                        Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 58, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(savingAccount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(currentAccount).addComponent(savingAccount))
                .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 329, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2)).addContainerGap()));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void savingAccountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {// GEN-FIRST:event_savingAccountActionPerformed
        BankAccount SC = new SavingsAccount();
        savingAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainMenu2.this.IB();
            }
        });
    }// GEN-LAST:event_savingAccountActionPerformed

    private void currentAccountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {// GEN-FIRST:event_currentAccountActionPerformed

        currentAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BankAccount CA = new CurrentAccount();
                MainMenu2.this.IB();
                String IB;
                transactionHistoryA.append("Opening Balance £" + IB + ".\n");

                Timer timer = new Timer();
                setVisible(true);
                TimerTask myTask;
                myTask = new TimerTask() {

                    int balance = Integer.parseInt(IB);

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Random num = new Random();
                        int dW = num.nextInt(2);
                        int randomNumber = num.nextInt(500);
                        dW = dW * 2;
                        dW = dW - 1;

                        if (((balance + dW * randomNumber)) < -200) {
                            int avail = balance + 200;
                            transactionHistoryA.append(
                                    "Deposit/ Withdraw : " + dW * randomNumber + " Operation can't be completed.\n");
                            transactionHistoryA.append(" Insufficient Funds.\n");
                            transactionHistoryA.append("Amount that can be withdrawn : £" + avail + ".\n");
                        } else {
                            balance = balance + (dW * randomNumber);
                            transactionHistoryA.append("Desposit/Withdraw : " + dW * randomNumber);
                            transactionHistoryA.append(".\n" + "Account Balance : " + balance + " .\n");
                            transactionHistoryA.append(".\n");
                        }

                        if (dW * randomNumber > 500) {
                            balance = balance + 10;
                        }

                    }

                };

            }
        });
    }// GEN-LAST:event_currentAccountActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting
        // code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.
         * html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // </editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton currentAccount;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JButton savingAccount;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea transactionHistoryA;

    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    public void IB() {
        BankAccount CA = new CurrentAccount();
        BalanceCheck = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Initial Balance"));
        CA.balance = BalanceCheck;
        transactionHistoryA.append("" + CA.balance + ".\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find where in your code it says to run a five second timer; would you mind pointing it our for me? Also, consider creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your code faster to read.

Comment: @ricky3350 "Timer timer = new Timer();
                setVisible(true);
                TimerTask myTask;
                myTask = new TimerTask() " Thats it there but when i try to set the 5 seconds it doesn't work

Comment: "A 5 second timer" refers to something that executes some code every five seconds, correct? If so, you may be using the wrong timer; look at [the timer you're using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), and [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), which may be the Timer you're looking for